# PHP array to jQuery array within <<<EOT

Tags: php, jquery

I have some PHP that outputs some jQuery code using `<<<EOT`. The PHP contains an array I want to use inside the jQuery, but can't get it to work.

The problem is with the jQuery array is always `null`. I've tried several ways of doing

PHP:

```
$myPHPVar = array( 'name' : 'data1', 'description' : 'data2');

function confirmation() {

    global $myPHPVar;

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var $myjQueryVar = <?php echo json_encode($myPHPVar); ?>
    </script>
    <?php

    var $confirmation = <<<EOT
<script>
function postToFeed() {
    var obj = {
      name: $myjQueryVar['name'],
      description: $myjQueryVar['description']
    };

    feed.post(obj);
}
</script>

<div><a href="#" onClick="postToFeed()">Share your results!</a></div>
EOT;

    return $confirmation;
}
```

In the code above, `$myjQueryVar` is always null. I've cut out irrelevant code and free-handed most of the above, but I think it accurately represents the logic of my code on this issue.

Is it apparent from the code above what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

In my code example above, I wrote:

```
$myPHPVar = array( 'name' : 'data1', 'description' : 'data2');
```

I don't know if it makes a difference, but the actual code I am using is:

```
$myPHPVar = array(
    "name"          => 'Odio a',
    "description"   => 'Phasellus viverra vel odio a laoreet.'
);
```

Still, after following @Jan suggestion below, the rendered output is:

```
function postToFeed() {
  var obj = {
  name: ,
  description: 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curly brackets inside the heredoc:

```
var obj = {
  name: '{$myjQueryVar['name']}',
  description: {$myjQueryVar['description']}
};
```

Additionally, as said in the comments, you are mixing JavaScript and PHP variables. This one works (using `$myPHPVar` instead):

```
<?php
$confirmation = <<<EOT
<script>
function postToFeed() {
    var obj = {
      name: '{$myPHPVar['name']}',
      description: '{$myPHPVar['description']}'
    };

    feed.post(obj);
}
</script>

<div><a href="#" onClick="postToFeed()">Share your results!</a></div>
EOT;

echo $confirmation;
?>
```

Comment: The rendered output shows `name: ,` and errors in Firefox with `SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','  name      : ,`

Comment: What is actually **in** `$myjQueryVar` ?

Comment: I've edited my question. I think it answers your question?

Comment: @rwkiii: `$myjQueryVar` is not a `PHP` but a `JavaScript` variable in your code, so it is empty!

Comment: I don't understand. I am using json_encode and echoing the output to $myjQueryVar in the rendered script code. I have one other PHP variable I am able to use in jQuery - it works fine, but it is not output within a heredoc.

Comment: I'll try your edit. Looks like smarty? Are the curly brackets due to being within a heredoc?

Comment: You were correct. I was confusing the jQuery and PHP vars. json_encode isn't needed at all. Your answer is correct except that the curly brackets need to be wrapped in single apostrophes. Thx.